# Question not being answered: Am I being mined for rep?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation, questions

I recently posted a Python related question. Rather than answers suggesting modifications to the code as posted, the only respondent suggested one change to make (adding a "[0]" to an above line of code) that resulted in no change in the script's behavior. He then accused me of modifying the wrong line, and stated his input had allowed me to get through the first lines of the script: Which were working before he provided any input whatsoever. He then requested I copy and paste my entire file structure, rather than simply showing me how to modify the Python script with user input to open a file from a particular location, and after being informed the script was being run from the same location (Desktop) as the file I was selecting by User Input. If a user is not answering a question directly, and they keep posting non-answers, are they obtaining Rep for doing so? Repeating myself multiple times over 3 days rather than getting a simple answer that allows me to continue the script project isn't really helpful, and I'm trying to understand why a high-rep user would do this, when it seems like a waste of my time, and theirs.

Comment: I have just looked at that question and although I'm not a python dev it looks like you want us to debug your code for something that looks like a simple problem. You might want to read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), specially the linked content at the end of that article and how to create an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'm simply asking how to get through the first two, already working parts of the script to work on the next working part of the script. The answers I've been given so far have zero net gain: My code worked the same before and after the multiple non-answers. Put another way: Each raw_input prompt displays, I can answer each, resulting in the same error I got before I posted the code. I'll take a second look at the How to ask link, but this should be a straightforward question for anyone who does use Python.

Comment: From your comment I get the impression you think you asked a perfect question and you're upset that those that tried to help aren't qualified enough to do so. Is that the correct interpretation?

Comment: It sounds like the OP is genuinely trying to help you. That doesn't mean that the advice being dished out is actually **helpful**, just that there is no malicious intent. Sometimes unhelpful advice is a function of how the question was (mis)interpreted or sometime an answerer just thinks that they have incite to provide, even if incorrect. If the user has exerted any amount of effort in trying to work with you, I tend to give them the benefit of the doubt, regardless of what motives they may have. After all, you just may end up getting your problem solved...

Comment: @rene: Absolutely not. I'm discouraged the suggested change resulted in no net gain: The first two prompts still show up exactly as they did before, followed by the same error, and the person who answered patted themselves on the back for "fixing the first two lines," and has now moved on to blaming my file system, when anyone can cut and paste the code and see the first two prompts function with or without his suggested change.

Comment: Ok, good to hear we agree that you asked a question that could be improved...

Comment: @Ender A third party commented that the answer in question isn't beneficial and is actually incorrect. You have a recourse when that happens: You can point out that the answer is wrong. Over time, this leads to downvotes, which may encourage a self-delete.

Comment: Looks like I will need to be more careful with what questions I ask in the future, as @rene seemed miffed enough (for whatever reason) as to report this question, downvote my original question and report it when I attempted to clarify it. I don't believe I had enough rep to mark the answer as "not useful" at the time.

Comment: How do you know that rene downvoted you?  Do you have a hidden camera focused on his/her computer screen?

Comment: @santiago: the tone of responses from rene ITT, and that my original question was reported and received an additional down vote immediately after rene's snarky reply here. Wonderful attitude, by the way. Hope your day is going well!

Comment: I only tried to explain how I looked at your question and that you didn't seem to be aware that you could improve as well. That was what I was trying to express and as you posted a similar but much better question on SO I think I succeeded in that. And with that the internet became a better place. And posting on meta always gives you the risk of the meta effect. Not something I like but it is part of the deal when posting here. You get exposure, that can go two-ways.

Comment: @Ender as voting is anonymous, there is only assumptions which are not facts.  I can not see where rene was in any way anything but polite and helpful.

Answer (score 10):

No, the only time they are awarded reputation is when their answer is upvoted, or accepted.

From the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30588229/python-document-search-script-keep-getting-typeerror-coercing-to-unicode-nee), it appears he's trying very hard to help you. I don't know python well enough to know how helpful he is actually being, but it doesn't appear that he's being malicious or mean in any way.

If you can't answer his questions and he can't help you further, then your only real choice is to wait and see if someone else tries to answer your question.  I'd try to stick it out with the one person who's trying to help though.

Comment: My concern here is that help isn't moving forward. As mentioned above, he's congratulated himself for "fixing the first two lines of code" that already worked: They supplied prompts without adding the [0] he suggested, and I would like to move on to the next error. Perhaps it's how I'm asking the question.

Comment: @Ender Yes, it is how you are asking the question. The prose description of your goal and what the code actually does diverge quite a bit. When this happens people don't know whether the description or the code is authoritative.

Comment: @Louis Thanks, good to know.